# Multiple instances of one component in React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation, components

I am new to React Native and am working on a simple app, the app loads data structured like file folder hierarchy, so at top level, when a item is clicked, I want to switch to next level and Etc. every level has the same data, I guess I need to use the same component, I want to use react navigation to switch between levels, but I cannot do this because the same component is used.

Of course you can say just change the components' state with different data, but I need the navigation animation effect and navigating to upper level when click the back navigation component at the top.

Please help, thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxrJT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using StackNavigation, using "push" is the answer,
this.props.navigation.push('ScreenName');

see this link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html